# Using generic type of model through interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two models like:

```
public class ModelA {.....}
public class ModelB {.....}
```

Now, I have a generic interface like:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<int> MethodA(TEntity entity);
    Task<int> MethodB(TEntity entity);
}
```

Now, there is another interface that inherits the previous interface like below. But I do not want it to be just specific to ModelA. I want it to be a generic model. Because MethodA will be referencing ModelA and MethodB will be referencing ModelB.

```
public interface ITestRepository : IRepository<ModelA>
{
    Task<bool> AdditionalMethodA(int id);
    Task<bool> AdditionalMethodB(int id);
}
```

And I want to implement the main class like this. I want to pass ModelA to MethodA and ModelB to MethodB.

```
public class MainRepository : ITestRepository
{
    public Task<int> MethodA(ModelA modelA) {......}
    public Task<int> MethodB(ModelB modelB) {......}
}
```

How can I refactor the above code so that I am able to have the generic type of model? Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: just make `ITestRepository` generic.

Comment: You should consider making ITestRepository generic as well.

Comment: There is nothing tying together `ModelA` to `ModelB`. So they cannot be used interchangeably in generic functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is one method per interface, and then implement multiple interfaces.

```
public class ModelA {}
public class ModelB {}

public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<int> Method(TEntity entity);
}
public interface ITestRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<bool> AdditionalMethod(int id);
}

public class MainRepository : ITestRepository<ModelA>, ITestRepository<ModelB>
{
    public Task<int> Method(ModelA entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public Task<int> Method(ModelB entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public Task<bool> AdditionalMethodA(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public Task<bool> AdditionalMethodB(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    Task<bool> ITestRepository<ModelA>.AdditionalMethod(int id)
    {
        return AdditionalMethodA(id);
    }
    Task<bool> ITestRepository<ModelB>.AdditionalMethod(int id)
    {
        return AdditionalMethodB(id);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mainTest = new MainRepository();
        var a = new ModelA();
        var b = new ModelB();

        int xA = await mainTest.Method(a);
        int xB = await mainTest.Method(b);

        bool yA = await mainTest.AdditionalMethodA(0);
        bool yB = await mainTest.AdditionalMethodB(0);
    }
}
```